# Table top border won't color

Tags: html, css, colors, border, css-tables

Maybe I'm overlooking something here, but I can't figure out how to color the top-borders of the td-elements.

```
  table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
  }

  td {
    border: 2px solid #000;
  }

  tr:hover td {
    border-color: #F55;
  }
```

It works as expected, except the top border isn't colored.

http://jsfiddle.net/45CSj/

Comment: You want to colr th or you want to coloe the top of td?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using <s>`border-collapse: collapse;`</s> instead use [`border-collapse: separate;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) with [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) set to `0`

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/45CSj/4/)

Comment: the problem is another,hover the td

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful-

table{border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0px}

table td{border: 1px solid #000;}

tr:hover td {border: 1px solid #F55; }

but this will show double border around the cells/rows.